# How to this win10 cmd command work on win7?

Tags: windows, cmd

I want to make the following commands work on windows 7 but it seems like Add-VpnConnection is not recognized on windows 7

```
set server_addr="Your VPN Server IP (or DNS name)"
# Create VPN connection
powershell -command "Add-VpnConnection -Name 'My IKEv2 VPN' -ServerAddress '%server_addr%' -TunnelType IKEv2 -AuthenticationMethod MachineCertificate -EncryptionLevel Required -PassThru"
# Set IPsec configuration
powershell -command "Set-VpnConnectionIPsecConfiguration -ConnectionName 'My IKEv2 VPN' -AuthenticationTransformConstants GCMAES256 -CipherTransformConstants GCMAES256 -EncryptionMethod AES256 -IntegrityCheckMethod SHA256 -PfsGroup None -DHGroup Group14 -PassThru -Force"
```

Comment: Is the [VpnClient module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/vpnclient/?view=win10-ps) available in the versions of PowerShell that are available for Windows 7?

Comment: I don't think so, I guess that's the problem @AndrewMorton

Comment: PowerShell 7.1.2 is available at http://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell  It will be `pwsh.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

#### `Add-VpnConnection` is not recognized on windows 7

`Add-VpnConnection` is part of PowerShell 4.0 which is built in to Windows versions8.1+

You will need to install it on Windows7.

See [How to Install Windows PowerShell 4.0 - TechNet Articles - United States (English) - TechNet Wiki](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21016.how-to-install-windows-powershell-4-0.aspx) for the files required depending on your version of Windows.

If you want to install the latest version of PowerShell (7.1.2) on Windows 7 see [How to Install PowerShell 7.1 in Windows 7, Windows 8, and Windows 10 | Tutorials](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/151734-how-install-powershell-7-1-windows-7-windows-8-windows-10-a.html) and [Release v7.1.2 Release of PowerShell · PowerShell/PowerShell · GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/tag/v7.1.2)

Comment: if PowerShell must be installed, is there any reason not to install the current 7.1.2?

Comment: I could successfully upgrade the PS to 5.1 but still I get same error @DavidPostill